# Find all the properties of tetrahedron if the lengths of all the edges are known.

Tags: geometry

The task here seems simple but is, in fact, something that I don't really know how to solve. Say, you have a tetrahedron with edges of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7. The easiest here would be to calculate the surface area by using Heron's formula. But then for the volume, you need to either somehow calculate the length of one of the heights, or find a formula similar to Heron's one, that would let you calculate the volume by either using edges or sides. Does anyone have an idea about how to do that?

Comment: There is a Heron-type formula for the volume of a tetrahedron

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron

Comment: It is doubtful that  all the properties can be computed because different from the triangle case the lengths of the edges alone do not determine the tetrahedron unambiguously.

Comment: To elaborate on @user's comment: You need to know not only the edge's lengths, but their *arrangement*. For surface area, you need to know which collections of three edges actually form the triangular faces; for volume, [this "Heron-type" formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Heron-type_formula_for_the_volume_of_a_tetrahedron) cares which pairs of edges are opposite each other.

Comment: This  rises an interesting question how many different (up to isometry) tetrahedra can be constructed from 6 edges of different lengths. I would bet on 30, provided that any triple satisfy triangle inequality.